# New file in template is not accessed

Tags: buildbot

I am trying to display results in a web page. I want to link this from the waterfall page of buildbot. But when I use`<a href="link to the page">click</a>` , the required web page does not open. I have placed this new web page in the templates directory. Is there something more that needs to be done?

Comment: What are the results that you want to display? Results produced by one your builds?

Comment: Yes. I want to have a list of links from which user can download the zipped files. But I do not know which server side script to use or any buildbot specific techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the results you want to display are produced by one of your builds,
the waterfall web templates are not relevant, since they are templates
for the *whole* waterfall, including all builds, whether or not they
are builds that produce these particular results.

If you wish to provide links to some files generated by a build, you select
a buildstep in the build, or create one for the purpose, that will provide
those links within its status box in the waterfall display (e.g. in the
way that a `ShellCommand` buildstep provides a link to its `stdio` log).
For example, you might just add a final step to the build with the description
*Report* or *Publish*.

You must write a customized `BuildStep` class to execute the step that you select
or create. Your customized `BuildStep` class must be derived from [`LoggingBuildStep`](http://thomas.apestaart.org/download/tmp/buildbot/api/html/buildbot.process.buildstep.LoggingBuildStep-class.html),
or from a class, such as `ShellCommand`, that is already derived from `LoggingBuildStep`.

The necessary customization is to override the `createSummary` method with
your own implementation, and in that implementation call the `addURL` method to adds URL(s)
to the file(s) you want to publish to the buildstep's status box. You can add as
many URLs as you like. Here is an outline example:

```
class ReportingStep(ShellCommand):
    ...
    command = ['upload','report',to','some','server']
    ...
    def createSummary(self,log):
        ...
        url = "url/to/the/report/on/the/server"
        self.addURL("Report", url)
```

Now, when `ReportingStep` completes, its status box will contain
a link labelled `Report` to the report that the step has uploaded to the server.

Google "buildbot buildstep createSummary" for more leads.

> What if my files are saved locally and for now I just want the user to have a link to download the zipped files? 
>   From what I understand, the above customization will help provide an external url.

The user clicks a link that is served from your *buildmaster*. If your
build just saves these files locally, then they're saved on the *buildslave*.
So unless your buildslave is on the same machine as the buildmaster then the  link has to be URL to an "external" file.

On the other hand, if your buildstep uploads the file to *the buildmaster*,
then the link *can* be a link to local file - local on the buildmaster, which
is serving the link.

If your buildslave *is* on the same machine as your buildmaster, then obviously
you don't need to do any uploading:

```
addURL("Report",file:///path/to/the/zipfile.zip)
```

But remember, if you want the content at these links to be persistent then
`/path/to/the/zipfile.zip` had better not be somewhere that gets clobbered
by every build.

Comment: What if my files are saved locally and for now I just want the user to have a link to download the zipped files? From what I understand, the above customization will help provide an external url.

Comment: The proposed solution seems to be what I am looking for. However for the addURL("Report",file:///path/to/the/zipfile.zip) part, I still need to customize the LoggingBuildStep class right? Since this edit will allow us to pass the url?

Comment: Yes. To add custom URLs to the status of a buildstep it must be executed by a custom class derived from LoggingBuildstep, or from a class already derived from LoggingBuildstep, such as ShellCommand. There is no other way you can make the `addURL` calls you need to make.

Comment: http://thomas.apestaart.org/download/tmp/buildbot/api/html/buildbot.process.buildstep-pysrc.html#BuildStep.addURL - Please see the addURL method. Seems like it is already implemented here!

Comment: Yes, it is implemented. That's why I said you can *use* it when you *override* `createSummary`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83264/discussion-between-277roshan-and-mike-kinghan).